# Error building project after uploading UI to tfs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I'm very confused and i was hoping to get some insight into this. I have been working on a project for a few months and everything was going great until i decided to upload the UI to TFS for a front-end dev to work on.

This is multi layered project consisting of Data, Business and UI. I have uploaded many projects before but never had this issue. I have taken a screen capture to help explain the problem. As it's my first time running into this issue, I'm not sure how to explain.

[image: Build errors]

Any help on this would be great, thank you in advanced.

Comment: Hi @rene could you elaborate slightly more? Thank you.

Comment: I see that someone has marked this question with "This question may already have an answer here" That may be true and have similarities but the fact that the question has no answers marked as answered does not really help. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: @rene yes certainly. i'll keep you posted.

Comment: can we establish whether you are actually trying to build the process templates on your local machine and whether this is really related to your UI check in. that screenshot looks as though the build templates are included in your webUI project and are failing to compile due to references, but was it your intention to compile them anyway?

Comment: @rene after reviewing the link above. There was only one answer that could potentially be the issue but in my case it's not. I repeatedly checked the XamlAppDef file and i can clarify i did not have any spaces. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @JustTFS Thank you! For some reason the "BuildProcessTemplates" folder was included within my project. So when tying to build the project i guess it was overriding the build process?! When mapping a project to tfs be sure your don't accidentally include the "BuildProcessTemplates". Solving the issue was simply excluding. Again thank you. I wish i could mark this as answered.

Comment: You can [self answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question. I retracted my close vote.

Comment: rene i would love to self answer this but unfortunately i didn't solve the issue and would more than likely be unfair on @JustTFS. Much appreciated for the retraction. Regards.

Comment: Glad to help, have added answer

Comment: @JustTFS marked as answered, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your check in files, looks like the build templates have been accidentally included.